# Realm Results object type

Tags: ios, swift, realm

This is really basic but I just can't find how to get all objects of a type from a Realm database using Swift. Yes, yes:

```
var dogs = try! Realm().objects(Dog)
```

but what if I want to declare and initialize the dogs variable beforehand and load objects into it later? Like:

```
var dogs = ???
dogs = realm.objects(Dog)
```

What should the type of variable dogs be in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Realm.objects(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm7objectsuRxCS_6ObjectrFMxGCS_7Resultsx_) has the following signature:

```
public func objects<T: Object>(type: T.Type) -> Results<T>
```

The signature tells you that when you call the function as `realm.objects(Dog)`, the return type will be `Results<Dog>`.

If you wish to declare the variable and initialize it later in the same function, you can simply separate the declaration from the initialization, like so:

```
let dogs: Results<Dog>

// …

dogs = realm.objects(Dog)
```

If you are declaring a member variable and need to initialize it after `init`, you should declare as an optional and using `var`:

```
var dogs: Results<Dog>?

// …

dogs = realm.objects(Dog)
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasted an hour and ten minutes on this. One wonders why Realm docs would use type inference in their most basic examples, like website ink is expensive or something.

Comment: The Realm documentation attempts to use idiomatic Swift. Adding explicit type information would obscure readability in many cases rather than helping. The API reference documentation contains detailed information about the types involved.

Answer (score -2):

As well as Results you can also use List. This is useful if you are returning objects in a One:Many example.

In the case where you have two models Country and City, where a Country can have many cities.

```
var rlmCountry: Country!
var rlmCities: List<City>?

rlmCities = rlmCountry.cities
```

Comment: Yea, it's bad swift to force anything.