# How to Switch to MainThread for accessing Realm Object

Tags: ios, swift, realm, grand-central-dispatch, realm-mobile-platform

The snippet below is where I'm fetching all the data in my `resultEvents` and there I'm having this problem.

Sometimes when this below code is get execute my *current thread* is not on `MainThread` so how can I change my current thread to MainThread? I'm using  `resultEvents` on tableView's `cellforRow`  method that's why I need to do this on `MainThread`.

Is `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` what I need here?

If so, then I'm not able to use it cause I'm getting this error while accessing `resultEvents` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async`:

> error: variable 'resultEvents' captured by a closure before being initialized

and I can't initialize it with some dummy or empty data according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486167/realm-results-object-type) and [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1862).

My code is below:

```
var resultEvents: Results<REvents>

print("realm012: ",realm , Thread.current)
/// MARK: Realm Fetching
if Thread.isMainThread {
    resultEvents =  realm.objects(REvents.self).sorted(byProperty: "created", ascending: false)
} else { 
    // Here how can i change my currentThread to Main, so that i can access this realmObject on TableView's CellForRow method.
    let bgRealm = try! Realm()
    resultEvents = bgRealm.objects(REvents.self).sorted(byProperty: "created", ascending: false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [`DispatchQueue.main.async`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchqueue#symbols) is what you are looking for :)

Try declaring your `resultEvents` variable like this:

```
var resultEvents: Results<REvents>!
```

setting it to `nil` initially.

---

For the record, you might need `DispatchQueue.main.sync` instead depending on your specific logic. For instance, if you need to access `resultEvents` further down your code, etc.